# Android ConstraintLayout : layout_constraintDimensionRatio Not working

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

So I am trying to create a view that contains a ScrollView.  The ScrollView contains 2 columns of 4 ImageButton.  I want the ImageButton to always be square so I am using **layout_constraintDimensionRatio=1:1**.  I am also using **layout_constraintHorizontal_weight=0.5** so that each ImageButton should be 50% wide

However each square is showing up 100% wide?

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Your story starts here"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left_main_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_main_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="300px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name"
                android:padding="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left_main_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_main_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:text="Choose what matters to you"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left_main_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_main_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/left1"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title2"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/left2"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left_main_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right1"
                app:srcCompat="@color/colorAccent" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/right1"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title2"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/right2"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left1"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_main_guideline"
                app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/left2"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/left1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/left3"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left_main_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right2"
                app:srcCompat="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/right2"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/right1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/right3"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left2"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_main_guideline"
                app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/left3"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/left2"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/left4"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left_main_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right3"
                app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/right3"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/right2"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/right4"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left3"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_main_guideline"
                app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/left4"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left_main_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right4"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/left3"
                app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/right4"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left4"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_main_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/right3"
                app:srcCompat="?attr/colorControlHighlight" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:text="See your O2 Home Story"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rightBottomButton" />

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/left_main_guideline"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.0"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/right_main_guideline"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1.0"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="360dp" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the image buttons right2, right3 and right4 to constrain their tops to left2, left3 and left4 respectively. Like this for right2:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/left2"
```

Also, remove the following line from left1. I think this is just an error.

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/left2"
```

This will give you a display that looks like [this demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLxpp.gif).

I don't have an answer for why this works. If any other reader knows, I would definitely like to hear the answer. Here is the XML:

**Changed XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Your story starts here"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left_main_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_main_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="300px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Name"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left_main_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_main_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Choose what matters to you"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left_main_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_main_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/left1"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left_main_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title2"
                app:srcCompat="@color/colorAccent" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/right1"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/right2"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left1"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_main_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title2"
                app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/left2"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/left3"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left_main_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/left1"
                app:srcCompat="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/right2"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/right3"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left2"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_main_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/left2"
                app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/left3"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/left4"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left_main_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right3"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/left2"
                app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/right3"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/right4"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left3"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_main_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/left3"
                app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/left4"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left_main_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right4"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/left3"
                app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/right4"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left4"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_main_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/left4"
                app:srcCompat="?attr/colorControlHighlight" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:text="See your O2 Home Story"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/left_main_guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.0"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/right_main_guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1.0"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="360dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```